# Flutter multi environment

Tags: flutter, environment-variables

Hello everyone,
I need some help with multi environment in flutter.

Expected result:

- multi environments (like prod / dev / staging)
- easy for change and visually separated (it could be 3 diff or one file with good structure)
- variables could be used in native code
- support of **Android Studio** flutter run
- possible to run from **Xcode**

Quite easy, right? ) No!

What I have tried:

- **flutter_dotenv** - not support native code
- **flutter_config** - it was quite good, but to run flutter with env you should write `ENFILE=.env.dev flutter run ...`, so with this approach you loose advantages of Flutter run console in android studio and flutter app not rerun automatically
- `--dart-define=` approach - long lines of run command, hard to read, hard to change, code repetition for `flutter run` and `flutter build`

It looks like I have missed something, I have come from react-native ant all this question resolved by `react-native-config` and command in `package.json` but in flutter I don't see ways for predefined command like in package json (only `Run/Debug Configurations`). But flutter run don't support env files but just sh scripts possible run with ENFILE but they don't trigger the flutter run console.

I will be grateful for your help ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution to use android run configurations with.

The schema will be next:

- create env files
- create different run android configuration (dev, stage, prod)
- save android run configurations to project
- write script to update android run configurations from .env files

This schema faced all requirements except "possible to run from Xcode". In common it still possible to run project from Xcode but to change configuration inside xcode to other env it still necessary to run project from android run configuration.

There more information and code example:

- [Flutter Multi Environment with dart-define](https://medium.com/@nikita.filimonau/flutter-multi-environment-with-dart-define-6bce4bfb94bf)
- [GitHub code example](https://github.com/nikita-filimonau/flutter_demonstration_app)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you did miss something past flutter 1.17 you can use compile-time vars ie via `--dart-define=`

`$ flutter run --dart-define=SOME_VAR=SOME_VALUE --dart-define=OTHER_VAR=OTHER_VALUE`

```
class EnvironmentConfig {
  static const SOME_VAR = String.fromEnvironment('SOME_VAR');
  static const OTHER_VAR = String.fromEnvironment('OTHER_VAR');
}
```

Note that anything with URLs in it is different from android vs ios and you have more hoop on ios to get it to turn outright.

follow up refs are:

https://medium.com/@tatsu.ukraine/what-you-should-know-before-you-upgrade-flutter-in-your-project-with-compile-time-variables-3ec3d2e9ba79

https://itnext.io/flutter-1-17-no-more-flavors-no-more-ios-schemas-command-argument-that-solves-everything-8b145ed4285d

Comment: Have you read my question?
Third point!!!! `--dart-define= approach`

My command looks like this:
flutter run --flavor dev --dart-define=FLUTTER_APP_ADD_MOB_APP_ID_IOS=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~2594085930 --dart-define=FLUTTER_APP_ADD_MOB_APP_ID_ANDROID=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~4354546703 --dart-define=FLUTTER_APP_ADD_MOB_BANNER_IOS=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4339318960 --dart-define=FLUTTER_APP_ADD_MOB_BANNER_ANDROID=ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8865242552

Don't worry this is test keys ))
If you have good way to structure that, please provide that!